# rsyslogd not listening udp 514

Tags: rsyslog, udp

I have Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 with rsyslog 5.8.11

udp 514

[image]

$UDPServerRun 514 
and
$InputTCPServerRun 514 are uncommented. Why it is not listening to that udp port?

Answer (score 2):

For your rsyslog listen to the UDP port that you defined, you need to discomment or include this module on your rsyslog.conf:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

On the client that is going to send the messages to the server, use this syntax for UDP:

```
*.* @SERVER-IP:UDP-PORT
```

You can manipulate the above example as you wish. Like:

```
local1.* @SERVER-IP:UDP-PORT
```

For TCP is two @'s:

```
auth.* @@SERVER-IP:UPD-PORT
```